# Detecting shape using numpy for image of people

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, python-imaging-library

I am trying to do face detection without using `opencv`.

- I am filtering the image to find edges of the image.
- I am widening the edges of the image for clear.
- I want to recognise the shape in the image like round for face or recognising shape of eye nearly something like round or square shape.

Is there any code or tutorial available to help me detect shape in image which is mainly groups of people or one person photo?

I do not want to use `opencv` for this.

Comment: I'm totally fine with not using opencv, but that is not how face detection is done. Do you actually want to perform the face detection step mentioned at the beginning of your question, or do you want to measure your connected components ? If the later, edit your question to make it clear.

Comment: yes i want to do face detection but i do not want to use opencv. so i used sobel edge detection for the image than i want to recognise the shape for example round shape in general for human face using numpy or scipy or any otherway. because i do not know how to do face detection as i am very new to python. i also want to count the number of people present in image after face detection. i hope this cler explanation of what solution i am looking for. @mmgp

Comment: This sounds awfully like you are trying to solve the hackerrank face detection challenge

Answer (score 0):

Well, Hough Transform (HT) is one of the most common methods for detecting shapes (if this is the approach you want to take in your face detection code).

It is possible to code it from scratch using only numpy or, if you want to take an easier approach, you can look into scikit-image [Circular and Elliptical Hough Transforms](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_circular_elliptical_hough_transform.html)

It probably wont be as fast or as extensive (in terms of processing options) as opencv, but it should be enough.